# Error in file uploading in php

Tags: php, html

My HTML code

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name='image' >
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code(Only the line which is errorneous is mentioned)

```
    <?php
    list($waste,$extension) = explode("/",$_FILES["image"]["type"]);echo $extension;
    ?>
```

It is giving file extension if the file is an image but it's giving error in case of video.

**ERROR**

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  364904  {main}( )   ..\upload.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  364904  {main}( )   ..\upload.php:0
```

Please tell me how to make it work for video uploading also.

Comment: do a `var_dump($_FILES)` and see what the `['error']` code is, if any. The codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Dont rely on the `["type"]` to get an extension.

Comment: Then how can i get the extension

Comment: With pathinfo `$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
`

Comment: You are getting a PHP notice saying that the index `image` is undefined. You say that it works for images, but not for videos. Do you have a different `name` for your `<input type="file"` in the case of videos?

Comment: I tried all solutions and everything working fine for image but not for video

Comment: You have not been given any potential solutions yet. Post the output of `var_dump($_FILES)` for a video.

Comment: @MichelleSmith perhaps your hitting upload limit, Read `Marc B`'s comment

Comment: the output of var_dump($_FILES) is array empty

Comment: So the problem isn't with your PHP script. The file is not being sent. Is the video file too big?

Comment: Yeah I hit the max filesize.Thanks

Comment: Please also write ini_set functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ini_set function is

```
ini_set("max_filesize","150M");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if a variables available before you can start working on it and its obvious you need some basic on on how to work with `$_FILES` please see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

```
<?php

if (isset ( $_FILES ['image'] )) {
    $extension = pathinfo ( $_FILES ['image'] ['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    echo $extension;
}

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="file" name='image'> <input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for video files, the file size is too large (126 MB, as reported by OP). So the PHP script is never receiving the file.

There are a few places where you can look to adjust this. First, you can set a max file size in the HTML form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="157286400" /> <!-- 150 MB -->
```

Also, you may need to adjust some variables in you php.ini file:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: Please add ini_set function to increase max_upload_filesize

Comment: See the link for the values that you will want to change. The `ini_set` method should be simple from there.